# GCC undefined symbols for `throw_bad_array_new_lengthv` on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, boost

## TLDR

I am trying to build Boost from source on my Mac **with GCC** and it gives me linking errors for undefined symbols, and I don't know what's wrong with my setup (or compiler).

## Background

I have been happily switching between GCC and Clang on my mac for a while, and recently tried to introduce Boost's program options into the mix, and it seems my Mac builds Boost by default with Clang (installed with brew), and this introduces an incompatible ABI when I then try and use GCC. Following the advice from [Compile with GCC and Boost on Mac giving linking error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77069798/5134817) I am now trying to build Boost from source with GCC, but get the same sort of compiler warnings.

#### Trying to install boost and getting the linking errors

When I run the command `$ b2 --build-dir=$PWD/build toolset=darwin --with-program_options  stage` I get:

```
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 64-bit (cached) [1]
    - default architecture     : x86 (cached) [1]

[1] darwin-11.4.0

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
...
    - program_options          : building
...
    - wave                     : not building

...patience...
...found 973 targets...
...updating 4 targets...
darwin.link.dll /Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_program_options.dylib
ld: warning: option -no_dead_strip_inits_and_terms is obsolete and being ignored
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv", referenced from:
      __ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EEaSERKS7_.isra.0 in cmdline.o
      __ZNSt6vectorIN5boost15program_options12basic_optionIcEESaIS3_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS3_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS3_S5_EEDpOT_ in cmdline.o
      __ZNSt6vectorIN5boost15program_options12basic_optionIcEESaIS3_EE9push_backERKS3_ in cmdline.o
      __ZN5boost15program_options6detail7cmdline16parse_terminatorERSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS9_EE in cmdline.o
      __ZN5boost15program_options6detail7cmdline3runEv in cmdline.o
      __ZN5boost15program_options16ambiguous_optionC1ERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EE in options_description.o
      __ZN5boost15program_options16ambiguous_optionC2ERKS1_ in options_description.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    "g++" -dynamiclib -Wl,-single_module -install_name "libboost_program_options.dylib"  -o "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_program_options.dylib" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/cmdline.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/config_file.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/options_description.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/parsers.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/variables_map.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/value_semantic.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/positional_options.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/utf8_codecvt_facet.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/convert.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/winmain.o" "/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/split.o"      -headerpad_max_install_names -fPIC -m64 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wl,-dead_strip -no_dead_strip_inits_and_terms 

...failed darwin.link.dll /Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_program_options.dylib...
...skipped <p/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/stage/lib>libboost_program_options.dylib for lack of <p/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>libboost_program_options.dylib...
...skipped <p/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>libboost_program_options-variant-shared.cmake for lack of <p/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>libboost_program_options.dylib...
...skipped <p/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/stage/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.83.0>libboost_program_options-variant-shared.cmake for lack of <p/Users/oliver/boost_1_83_0_gcc/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/darwin-11.4.0/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>libboost_program_options-variant-shared.cmake...
...failed updating 1 target...
...skipped 3 targets...
```

Using my GCC compilers, generally they have seemed to work fine up until now, and I have tried this with a few GCC variants installed from either brew or macports, and they all throw this same error (I am not sure how to reproduce it minimally).

I am not really sure what's gone off in my setup, but suspect it might be something about how my compilers are setup and installed on mac and which c++ standard library they are trying to use, but I am neither clear on how to diagnose this nor fix it.